# Associative joint data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Rails newbie here, I have two models related by

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images

  class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
```

I understand you can get users images and I can also use my current_user method which returns info on my current user

```
@user.images or current_user.images
```

What if i want it to return both the image data and users data in one row like you would with normal sql.

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
JOIN images i
ON i.user_id = u.id etc..
```

What's the best and most efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Why do you need the data in this structure?

Comment: The same reason why people use joins in sql. I need the image data and it's corresponding user together in the same row :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query -

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
JOIN images i
ON i.user_id = u.id etc..
```

is equivalent to -

```
@user.joins(:images)
```

UPDATE:

To get only the certain fields -

```
@comments = @user.joins(:images).select("images.path, images.path_thumb, users.username")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what if i want to select only a few things e.g u.id, i.path, u.username, i.path_thumb etc